# Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart problem in package

Tags: r, recursion

I am trying to use a package in R that I found - Bayesian Macroeconomics in R (BMR) - and I stumbled in the following error after trying to estimate the MCMC for the model

```
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
Error in tryCatch(evalq((function (parameters)  : bad value
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
Error in parent.frame() : 
  'rho' must be an environment not promise: detected in C-level eval
Error during wrapup: R_Reprotect: only 0 protected items, can't reprotect index 33
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

After this error the R aborts the current session and I have to start a new one. I tried to look into the packages code to see if it was something to do with it, but I am not good enough to find out. I searched for it on google and some people have solved this problem using gc(), but it didn't work for me. This issue is already reported in the Package github repository, but it didn't receive any answers. I am really trying to work with DSGE without using MATLAB/Octave and this package was looking pretty good for it.

The code I am trying to replicate is this one:

```
rm(list=ls())

library(BMR)

source("nkm_model.R")

#

data(BMRVARData)
dsgedata <- USMacroData[24:211,-c(1,3)]
dsgedata <- as.matrix(dsgedata)
for(i in 1:2){
    dsgedata[,i] <- dsgedata[,i] - mean(dsgedata[,i])
}

#

obj <- new(dsgevar_gensys)
obj$set_model_fn(nkm_model_simple)

x <- c(1)

obj$eval_model(x)

#

lrem_obj = obj$lrem
lrem_obj$solve()

lrem_obj$shocks_cov <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0.125),2,2,byrow=TRUE)

sim_data <- lrem_obj$simulate(200,800)$sim_vals

sim_data <- cbind(sim_data[,3],sim_data[,5])

#

prior_pars <- cbind(c(1.0),
                    c(0.05))

prior_form <- c(1)

obj$set_prior(prior_form,prior_pars)

#

par_bounds <- cbind(c(-Inf),
                    c( Inf))

opt_bounds <- cbind(c(0.7),
                    c(3.0))

obj$set_bounds(opt_bounds[,1],opt_bounds[,2])

obj$opt_initial_lb <- opt_bounds[,1]
obj$opt_initial_ub <- opt_bounds[,2]

#

cons_term <- TRUE
p <- 1
lambda <- 1.0

obj$build(sim_data,cons_term,p,lambda)

mode_res <- obj$estim_mode(x,TRUE)

mode_check(obj,mode_res$mode_vals,25,1,"eta")

#

obj$mcmc_initial_lb <- opt_bounds[,1]
obj$mcmc_initial_ub <- opt_bounds[,2]

obj$estim_mcmc(x,50,100,100) # error here

var_names <- c("Output Gap","Output","Inflation","Natural Int","Nominal Int","Labour Supply",
               "Technology","MonetaryPolicy")

plot(obj,par_names="eta",save=FALSE)
IRF(obj,20,var_names=colnames(dsgedata),save=FALSE)
forecast(obj,10,back_data=10)
states(obj)
```

The error occurs in line 78:

```
obj$estim_mcmc(x,50,100,100)
```

Comment: Hello, Matheus. You must share a code example, a link does not met the requeriments, also the contents could change.